# Potential Energy of two atoms in diatomic molecule

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, potential-energy, molecules

> The potential energy of two atoms in a diatomic molecule is approximated by $U(r)=a/r^{12}−b/r^6$, where r is the spacing between atoms and a and b are positive constants.
>
> a) Find the force $F(r)$ on one atom as a function of $r$.
>
> b) Find the equilibrium distance between the two atoms.
>
> c) Is this equilibrium stable?
>
> d) Suppose the distance between the two atoms is equal to the equilibrium distance found in part A. What minimum energy must be added to the molecule to dissociate it-that is, to separate the two atoms to an infinite distance apart? This is called the dissociation energy of the molecule.
>
> e) For the molecule CO, the equilibrium distance between the carbon and oxygen atoms is 1.13×10−10m and the dissociation energy is 1.54×10−18J per molecule. Find the value of the constant a.
>
> f) Find the value of the constant $b$.

I have calculated the answer for part a and b which are $12ar^{-13}-6br^{-7}$ and $r=(2a/b)^(1/6)$ respectively.

But I have no idea whether part c is yes or no. And I do not dare to guess, because the annoying Mastering Physics will deduct marks if the answer is wrong. It deducts a lot of marks if the MC question have only two choices, just like this question.

And can you explain how to determine if it is stable in equilibrium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if the potential energy function looks like a minimum or a maximum at the equilibrium point.  If it looks like a minimum, then you have a stable equilibrium, like a ball rolling at the bottom of a bowl.  You can use the second derivative to test for a minimum-- it must be positive.